# For loops in python 3.0

Tags: function, for-loop

```
def func(x):
    res = 0
    for i in range(x):
        res+=i
    return res
print(func(4))
```

For is used for looping any thing inside its body
So according to that the result should be

```
0
1
3
6
```

but the result is only 6
why?

Comment: sorry for not being able to post image of my code because i dont have 10 reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only returning your last value.
You need to print inside the loop. Something along the following lines should work,

```
def func(x):
    res = 0
    for i in range(x):
        res+=i
        print(res)
    return res
func(4)
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I get the full loop . Thx for the help

Comment: @Electrocuted Just put the print statement, inside the loop. An alternative could be to create an array and return the array. Then the contents in the array can be printed.